# Notes with special sound effect

Tags: piano, digital-piano, effects-pedal

Please refer to this video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqpvE45-Cq0) for this question.
There are certain passages on the right hand the played notes seemed to have some special effect.

Am I right?  If so, how do you tell from the sheet music.

I personally like the sound without that special effect better.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the subject matter — identifying an "effect" — is off-topic here. The question could instead be asked on SE Music Fans, but would need to be rewritten to include more information. The help pages on that site will explain what more is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video has a string sound doubling the right hand piano line. From about 1:21 the string sound changes to oboe. There's nothing in the notated music to indicate this.

Comment: At beginning 0:05, how did she change the instrument  with both hands visible on the piano keys as you can see.

Comment: @EmilyJ Two possibilities: either she's using a foot pedal to switch sounds, or (more likely) the audio is pre-recorded and the video is of her miming to the audio.

Comment: @EmilyJ there are other possibilities, e.g. piano was recorded as MIDI and then edited, or patch changes were pre-recorded, or someone else was changing them...

Comment: @user1079505 Or the video of the hands was computer generated :)